# Cannot run Ableton (Mac OS X) "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: mac

When trying to run Ableton, to install it this is what I get:

```
Air-di-Elia:~ eliadoro$ /Users/eliadoro/Desktop/Ableton\ Live\ Suite\ v10\ 0\ 6\ MacOSX\ Incl\ Patched\ and\ Keygen-R2R/Ableton\ Live\ 10\ Suite.7z\ 2 ; exit;
-bash: /Users/eliadoro/Desktop/Ableton Live Suite v10 0 6 MacOSX Incl Patched and Keygen-R2R/Ableton Live 10 Suite.7z 2: cannot execute binary file
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Processo completato]
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

That filename ending in `.7z` means it's a "7-Zip"  compressed archive, not an executable binary file.

If you double-click a compressed archive file in the Finder, the Finder will automatically handle it by launching macOS's built-in tool that decompresses/expands archives.

If macOS's built-in unarchiver doesn't know 7-Zip, you'll need to download a tool that knows how to handle 7-Zip, and use that tool to unarchive your `.7z` file.